# What's the best way to find an object from a string in kotlin?

Tags: list, kotlin

I have an app that is reading an ingredients list.  At this point I've already retrieved a list of the 2500 most common ingredients.  So I've got a list of, say 10 ingredients as strings, and a list of 2500 ingredients, with names as well as other properties.  If an ingredient in this list of strings matches the name of an ingredient in the list of ingredients, I'd like to add it to another list third list, of ingredients that exist.  The only way I know how to do that is with basically a for loop.

I'd do it as

```
fun compareLists(listOfIng: List<String>): List<ListIngredientsQuery.Item> {
    var returnList = mutableListOf<ListIngredientsQuery.Item>()
    for (ing in listOfIng) {
        for (serverIngredient in MyApp.metaIngredientList!!) {
            if (serverIngredient.name() == ing) {
                returnList!!.add(serverIngredient)
            }
        }
    }
    return returnList
}
```

Which would technically work, but I have to imagine there's a better, faster way than iterating over 2500 items, as many times as there are Ingredients in an Ingredient list.  What is the like, proper, preferred by real developers, way of doing this.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

As each ingredient name is unique, you can use hash map for storing your 2500 ingredients with its name as the key. This way you do not need to loop over that huge collection any more, but just look thing up by the name and let the hash map deal with it.

Answer (score 3):

To put some code to what Marcin said, here is what I would do:

```
fun compareLists(listOfIng: List<String>) =
  MyApp.metaIngredientList!!
      .associateBy { it.name() }
      .let { metaIngredientMap -> listOfIng.mapNotNull { metaIngredientMap[it] }}
```

Or if we wanna avoid using !!

```
fun compareLists(listOfIng: List<String) =
  MyApp.metaIngredientList
      ?.associateBy { it.name() }
      ?.let { metaIngredientMap -> listOfIng.mapNotNull { metaIngredientMap[it] }}
      ?: emptyList<ListIngredientQuery.Item>()
```

Of course, ideally, you would want that MyApp.metaIngredientList to be already a Map and not convert it into a Map for each operation